# Cannot install Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-installation

I'm having trouble installing "Windows XP student edition" on my friend's computer.

My friend gave me her old computer, it was riddled with viruses and ran extremely slow Even the keyboard's key works، 5 seconds after holding it

I then tried to install Windows XP from a CD But to me the following error.

(Before I installed Windows scan it, with antivirus)

I see this error Before formatted Hard Drive and when booting from CD

[image]

How do I install it?

Comment: Please edit your question, it's hard to understand in its current form. Especially remove emoticons and multiple question marks, those don't make it clearer. When does the bluescreen pop up - does it happen instantly when booting from CD or later? Have you formatted the hard drive? (If not, DON'T do this yet)

Comment: @gronostaj ok,Thank you for your attention.Before formatted Hard Drive and when booting from CD.

Comment: @faranak50 Need integrate AHCI and RAID driver to install CD.

Comment: @STTR After installation, the problem will be solved?

Comment: @faranak50 The problem will not appear on the stage of installation or afterwards, if you spend the integration of drivers successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AHCI MassStorage driver Windows XP 32-bit/64-bit](http://forum.oszone.net/thread-135321.html)

[DriverPacks BASE 10.06](http://driverpacks.net/applications/latest)

[Latest DriverPacks](http://driverpacks.net/driverpacks/latest)

Answer (score 1):

Try booting into the pc with a live cd of a linux distro (maybe lubuntu because it's an old pc (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu)) and try formatting the hard drive completely. Then put the windows installation dvd back in the computer and install windows.